# Центрирование text внутри изображения path

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, svg

У меня есть подобный `svg`:

```html
        <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1565.61 896.1">
            <defs>
                <style>
                    .cls-1,.cls-2 {
                        fill:#b9b9b9;
                    }
                    .cls-1,.cls-2,
                    .cls-3,.cls-4,
                    .cls-5 {
                        stroke:#fff;
                        stroke-width:1.5px;
                    }
                    .cls-1,.cls-3 {
                        stroke-miterlimit:10;
                    }
                    .cls-3,.cls-4 {
                        fill:#cecece;
                    }
                    .cls-5{
                        fill:#fc9272;
                    }
                    path {
                        content: 'blabla';
                        color: red;
                        font-size:20px;
                    }
                    path:hover {
                        transition: .3s ease;
                        fill:#325288;
                    }
                </style>
            </defs>
            <title>Blank map of Kazakhstan</title>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M69.2,425.5" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-2" d="M241.8,518.1c-.1.1-.3.1-.4.2-.3.1-.5.1-.8.2A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,241.8,518.1Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M241.8,518.1c-.1.1-.3.1-.4.2-.3.1-.5.1-.8.2A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,241.8,518.1Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-3" d="M1195.9,323c-.5,1.7-1.3,1.6-3.9,4.9-2.4,3-2.7,4.4-4.8,5.4a11.24,11.24,0,0,1-2.7.8c-4.3,1.3-6.9,2.1-8.5,4.3a8,8,0,0,0-1.3,4.2c0,1.8.8,2.3,1.2,4.8a10.73,10.73,0,0,1,0,4c-.5,2.4-1.8,2.9-1.9,5.1a8.6,8.6,0,0,0,.5,2.6c1.8,6.9,1.9,7.3,2.5,7.8,1.4,1.2,2.3.3,4.8,1.9a6.65,6.65,0,0,1,2.7,2.8c.3.8.3,1.3-.1,4.5-.5,4.4-.6,5.2-1.3,6a5.58,5.58,0,0,1-2.9,1.6c-4.4,1.8-8.4,6.7-7.5,9.3.6,1.7,2.8,1.2,5.1,4a15.29,15.29,0,0,1,2,4.2c1.6,4.4,2.4,6.7,2.3,8.9a16.83,16.83,0,0,1-3.1,9.2c-1.6,2.7-2.2,4.2-3.8,4.7-2.3.8-3.7-1-6.3,0a8.89,8.89,0,0,0-3.3,2.6c-1.1,1.2-2,2.3-2.1,3.8-.2,2.3,1.8,4.2,2.8,5.2a8.17,8.17,0,0,0,4.5,2.4,6.62,6.62,0,0,0,3.5-.5c.2,1,.5,2,.7,3.1a3.49,3.49,0,0,0-3.8.5,3.26,3.26,0,0,0-.7,3.3c.7,2.4,3.7,3.4,4.2,3.5,2,.6,2.8,0,4.7.9.5.3,2.2,1.1,2.1,2.1s-1.8,1.3-3.8,2.6-2.9,3-4,4.9a21.24,21.24,0,0,0-2.6,8.9c-.6,5.9-1.3,12.6-1.9,20.2a5.5,5.5,0,0,0-3.8,2.1,7.79,7.79,0,0,0-.9,4.5c0,1.7.3,2.1-.1,3-.6,1.4-1.7,1.4-2,2.5-.2.7.1,1.4,2.4,4.6,2.6,3.7,3,4.1,3.7,4.5a9.16,9.16,0,0,0,3.9,1.3,4.42,4.42,0,0,0,2.6,0c1.9-1,.8-5,2.4-5.7.5-.2.8.1,3.4,1a39.72,39.72,0,0,0,4,1.2,18.59,18.59,0,0,0,2.8.5c0,.7-.1,1.4-.1,2,.3.6.6,1.3.9,1.9,0,8.9-.1,17.7-.1,26.6-.6.2-1.6.6-2.7,1a43,43,0,0,0-4.3,1.5,11.25,11.25,0,0,0-3.6,2.6H1167c-.5-.4-1.1-.8-1.6-1.2a25.93,25.93,0,0,1-8.9-.9,22.72,22.72,0,0,1-5.7-2.3c-1.6-1-2.3-1.9-4-2.5a12.21,12.21,0,0,0-4-.4c-3.4.1-5.6-1.2-8.6-2.2-7-2.6-14.5-2.6-16.8-2.6-3.9,0-9.2,0-13.7,2.3-.6.3-1.8,1-3.8,2-3.5,1.8-4.5,1.9-6.6,3.1-3.5,1.9-4.8,3.2-9.2,5.9-4,2.5-3.9,2-6,3.4-3.7,2.5-7,6.7-13.5,15-1.5,1.9-2.7,3.5-4.8,5.9-1.5,1.8-2.8,3.2-3.7,4.3h-15c-.7-.4-1.3-.8-1.9-1.1q-86.4-1.35-172.7-2.6H827c-.4-.4-.9-.8-1.3-1.2H793.6v.3a2.18,2.18,0,0,1-.5-.8c-.3-.6-.3-1.1-.2-3.7.1-2.9.1-3.7-.4-4.4a3.05,3.05,0,0,0-2-1.3c-13.5-.1-26.9-.1-40.4-.1l-15-2.1c-1.1-1.9-2.2-2.5-3-2.6s-1.1.1-1.8-.2c-1.2-.5-1.1-1.6-2.3-2.8s-1.4-.5-3.2-1.9c0,0-.5-.4-2.8-2.8a3.2,3.2,0,0,1-1.9-.7,3.51,3.51,0,0,1-1.2-2.1c-.3-1-1.6-4.7-4.1-5.6a7.54,7.54,0,0,0-2.1-.2c-2.1-.1-3.8,0-4.9,0-6.5-3.9-12.9-7.9-19.4-11.8-3.8-1.4-7.6-2.8-11.5-4.2a26.58,26.58,0,0,0-5.7-3.2,27.83,27.83,0,0,0-4.4-1.4c-3.7-1-4-.4-6.2-1.2a39.43,39.43,0,0,1-4.4-2.5,27.43,27.43,0,0,0-3.2-1.8c-2.1-.8-2.6-.4-4.1-1.2s-1.1-1.3-2.7-2.1c-1.3-.8-1.8-.5-2.8-1.2s-1-1.2-1.9-2.5a9.23,9.23,0,0,0-4.4-3.5c-1.3-.4-2.3-.2-4.1.1-2.3.4-2.8,1-5.7,1.5a20.15,20.15,0,0,1-3,.2c-1.1,0-1.7,0-1.8-.3-.2-.6,2-1.5,4.1-3.9a12.21,12.21,0,0,0,1.2-1.5h.1c3.2-2.9,6.3-5.8,9.5-8.7a7.5,7.5,0,0,0,1.9-.9c2.1-1.3,3-2.8,4.2-4.1,1.7-1.8,3.2-2.3,5.3-3.3,6.9-3.5,16-10.9,18.9-13.2a168.25,168.25,0,0,0,12.5-11.6,2.7,2.7,0,0,0,1.1-1.1,2.52,2.52,0,0,0,.3-1.9c-.4-1-1.7-.6-2.7-1.9-.6-.7-.3-1-1-2.1a10.82,10.82,0,0,0-1.7-1.9c-1-1.3-.2-2.1-1-3.9-.6-1.4-1-1.1-1.8-2.6-.9-1.8-.3-2.3-1.1-3.6a1.38,1.38,0,0,0-.3-.4l1.2-.9c.8-.7,1.5-1.2,3.2-2.7.6-.5,1.5-1.3,2.7-2.3,1.9-1.7,2.2-2.1,2.4-2.6a5.34,5.34,0,0,0,.2-3c-.4-2.4-1.8-3.3-1.3-4.3.2-.4.6-.6,2-1.1,2.6-.8,4.7-1.2,6.5-1.6,2.3-.6,3.5-.8,3.7-1.4.4-1-1.2-1.9-3-5.5-1.4-2.8-1.2-3.6-1-4.1.4-.7,1.2-.9,2-1.2a9.33,9.33,0,0,1,3.3-.3c3,.1,3.6.4,4.1-.1s.2-1.4.2-3.5a57.13,57.13,0,0,1,1.1-7.6c.4-2.3.5-2.6.8-2.8,1.2-.9,3.1.3,7.2,1.7,3.7,1.2,3.3.6,8.1,2,2.6.8,3.7,1.3,7.8,2.5,2.8.8,4.4,1.2,6.2.6a21.78,21.78,0,0,0,2.8-1.3,19,19,0,0,0,3.4-1.8,14.93,14.93,0,0,0,4.1-5.3c1-2,.7-2.1,1.3-2.7,1.1-1,2.1-.4,7.6-.3a2.88,2.88,0,0,1,1.9.5c.9.8.5,2,.9,2.2,1.3.5,8.3-10.8,9.1-13a2,2,0,0,1,1-1.2,2.17,2.17,0,0,1,1-.2c.8.1,2.5-.1,6.3-.7a19.32,19.32,0,0,1,2.8-12.7,19.64,19.64,0,0,1,7.4-6.5,30.33,30.33,0,0,1,4.2-1.6c1.2-2.1,7.8-14.1,13.9-21.9,2.3-2.9,3.5-4.4,5.3-5.8,3.6-2.8,6-2.9,7.1-5.5s-.7-4.3.5-6,3.5-.7,7.6-1.8,8.5-4,9.7-7.9a4.74,4.74,0,0,0,0-3.9,3.68,3.68,0,0,0-1.9-1.6,6.13,6.13,0,0,1,3.8-.5,8.72,8.72,0,0,0,3.1.5c1.7-.2,2.4-1.1,3.8-1.9s3.1-1,6.6-1.4c4.4-.5,6.7-.8,7.8.5.4.4.4.8.7,2.8.9,5.8,1.1,5.6,1.2,7.8.1,3.1.1,4.7-.9,5.9-1.5,1.8-3.8,1.2-4.2,2.6s1.3,3.4,3.1,4c.8.3.9,0,3.5,0a17.42,17.42,0,0,1,3.8.2c1.7.6,1.6,1.8,3.3,3.1a8.16,8.16,0,0,0,6.6,1.2c1.6-.5,2.6-1.6,4.5-3.5,2-2.1,2.3-3.2,3.5-3.3s1.5.9,3.5,1.9a11.66,11.66,0,0,0,5.9.9,14.9,14.9,0,0,0,5.4-1.4c1.9-.8,1.8-1.1,3.1-1.4s2.2-.2,5.4.2c2.2.3,4,.6,4.9.7.2,4.5.5,9.1.7,13.7a5.07,5.07,0,0,0,2.6.7,6.37,6.37,0,0,0,4.7-1.9c1.4-1.4.9-2.6,2.4-3.5.9-.6,1.1-.2,2.6-.7a12.22,12.22,0,0,0,4.9-3.4c1.5-1.6,1.3-1.8,2.3-2.5,1.2-.8,1.7-.4,4.1-1.3s2.9-1.7,3.1-2a3.56,3.56,0,0,0,.3-1.9c0-2.6-.8-3.5-1.1-6.3-.2-1.6-.3-2.5.3-3.4a4.49,4.49,0,0,1,3-1.9,16.7,16.7,0,0,1,3.1-.2,12.72,12.72,0,0,0,3.1-.4c1.4-.7.8-2.3,2.1-4.5.4-.6,1.8-3,4.2-3.6,1.2-.3,2.2-.1,3.6-1a3.07,3.07,0,0,0,1.3-1.2,5.06,5.06,0,0,0,.8-1.9c.5-2.4,3.7-5.4,6.7-5.6a14.84,14.84,0,0,1,2.5.5c3.8,1.1,4.1,2.2,6.4,2.4,1.6.1,2.5-.4,3.2.3a2.45,2.45,0,0,1,.5,2.3c-.1.3-.2.7-2.1,2.4-1.1,1-1.3,1.2-1.4,1.6-.1.7.6,1,1.1,2.1a6.34,6.34,0,0,1,.2,3.8,7.73,7.73,0,0,1-1.4,3.2c-.7,1-1.4,1.4-1.2,1.6s1.6-.2,2.7-.5c2.4-.8,2.4-1.1,3.6-1.4a7.21,7.21,0,0,1,5,.2c1.4.6,1.3,1.3,2.9,1.9a3.52,3.52,0,0,0,3.2.1,2.7,2.7,0,0,0,1.2-1.8c.2-1.4-1.1-1.9-.9-3,.1-.5.9-1.1,2.6-2.3s2-1.3,2.4-1.3c.9,0,1,.8,2.2,1.2a3.7,3.7,0,0,0,3.5-.3,2.9,2.9,0,0,0,1.4-2.6c-.3-1.4-2.2-1.4-2.3-2.6,0-.6.6-1.3,1.9-2.7a13.61,13.61,0,0,1,1.8-1.8c2.2-1.5,4.2.1,5.5-1.2,1-1,0-2,1.2-4.1a5.55,5.55,0,0,1,3.5-2.8,6.15,6.15,0,0,1,2.3.1,28.29,28.29,0,0,0,5.9-.1c2.5-.3,5-.7,5.7-2.3a15.11,15.11,0,0,0,.6-3.5,4.64,4.64,0,0,1,.3-1.7c.5-.6,1.3-.8,3.3-1,3.5-.3,3.6-.2,4.3-.5s.8-.7,2.7-2.8c2.3-2.5,3.2-2.9,3.2-4.1a2.26,2.26,0,0,0-1.2-2.1c-.6-.3-1.3-.1-2.6.2a6.35,6.35,0,0,0-2.1.9,6,6,0,0,0-1.1,1c-.5.5-.5.7-.7.8-.6.3-1.6-.3-2.2-1-.8-1-.4-1.7-1.1-3.2-.6-1.3-1-1.1-2.1-2.7-.3-.4-2-3-1.2-3.9.4-.4,1.3-.3,1.7-.2,1.4.3,1.5,1.2,2.8,1.7a5.15,5.15,0,0,0,3.1,0,7.1,7.1,0,0,0,2.5-1.6c1.9-1.6,6,0,8.6,1.3-.1.1-.2.1-.2.2-.2,1,3.6,3,7.8,4.3,4.4,1.4,5.7.8,6.7,2.2,1.2,1.7.6,4.4-.1,7.9-.5,2.2-1,3.4-.5,5.3a19.85,19.85,0,0,1,.9,2.6,6.48,6.48,0,0,1-.6,4c-.9,1.6-1.8,1.2-3.1,2.8s-1.4,3.7-1.5,5.5c-.1,2-.2,3.3.7,4.2.7.7,1.7.9,3.7,1.2s3.3.6,4.7,0,1.1-1.1,2.4-1.8c1.9-1,3.9-.6,6.3-.2,2.9.5,2.8,1.1,4.8,1.2,1.7,0,2.4-.4,3.9,0,.4.1,2.3.7,2.6,1.9a1.8,1.8,0,0,1-.3,1.2c-.5,1.1-1.2,1.2-1.7,2a3.57,3.57,0,0,0,.2,3.6,2.78,2.78,0,0,0,1.6,1.3,4.4,4.4,0,0,0,2.7-.2c2.8-.7,2.8-1.3,3.6-1.1,1.5.3,1.4,2,3.6,3.2,1.2.6,1.3.2,2.4.7,1.4.8,1.4,1.8,3.6,5.7,1.2,2.1,1.9,3.1,1.9,3.2.8,1,1.4,1.7,1.3,2.6a2.59,2.59,0,0,1-.7,1.5c-.8.9-1.6.7-3.5,1.5a16.88,16.88,0,0,0-3.3,1.9,8.58,8.58,0,0,0-1.9,1.6,4.91,4.91,0,0,0-.6,3.1c.3,1.1.9,1.2,1.1,2.4s-.4,1.4-.1,1.9c.5,1,3.4,1.1,5.2-.2,1.5-1.1.8-2.2,2.2-3.6,1.2-1.2,1.8-.5,5.7-2.2,2.2-1,3.3-1.5,3.8-2.4a2.66,2.66,0,0,1,1.2-1.2,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,1.2-.1,85.21,85.21,0,0,0,12.6.2c1-.1,1.5-.1,2.2-.2a17.26,17.26,0,0,0,6.1-2.5,18.65,18.65,0,0,1,2.8-1.6,6.28,6.28,0,0,1,2.5-.6,4.14,4.14,0,0,1,2.5,1.1c1.3,1,1,1.9,2.2,2.6.2.1,1.3.8,2.1.4s.5-1.3,1.2-2.4a8.22,8.22,0,0,1,2.3-1.8,16.59,16.59,0,0,1,3.8-1.8,5.88,5.88,0,0,1,3.4-.3c1.2.3,1.2.9,2.8,1.7,1,.4,2.4,1.1,3.3.5.7-.5.7-1.6.7-2.4a19.07,19.07,0,0,0-.5-2.6,8.92,8.92,0,0,1,0-3.3,24.9,24.9,0,0,1,1.1-2.6c.6-1.8.2-2.2.7-3.9a15.28,15.28,0,0,1,2-3.6c1.3-2,1.9-2.9,2.6-3.4,1.8-1.2,4.1-.8,5.8-.5a12.23,12.23,0,0,1,6.8,3.8c1,1.2.9,1.7,1.9,2.2,1.8,1.1,3-.2,5.5.4,1.2.3,2.8,1.5,6,4a12.92,12.92,0,0,1,2.2,1.9c2.3,2.9,1.9,6.8,1.9,7.1-.1,1.3-.3,2.4-.3,2.4-.3,1.8-.6,2.4-.3,3.1a2.61,2.61,0,0,0,1.6,1.1,6.15,6.15,0,0,0,1.1.3C1196.3,321.3,1196.2,322.1,1195.9,323Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <text x="170" y="335" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">1</text>
            <text x="230" y="455" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">2</text>
            <text x="260" y="675" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">3</text>
            <text x="430" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">4</text>
            <text x="620" y="595" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">5</text>
            <text x="670" y="205" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">6</text>
            <text x="830" y="75" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">7</text>
            <text x="900" y="235" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">8</text>
            <text x="900" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">9</text>
            <text x="860" y="700" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">10</text>
            <text x="990" y="670" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">11</text>
            <text x="1200" y="670" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">12</text>
            <text x="1350" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">13</text>
            <text x="1130" y="185" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">14</text>
        </svg>
```

В нём я добавил `text`, чтобы нумеровать количество объектов у определённой области, но теперь я не знаю как обратиться к `text`, совершив событие над `path` (например наведение курсора), чтобы изменить цвет текста, как можно прикрепить `text` к `path`, или как обращаться к `text`, если буду устанавливать координаты так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> теперь я не знаю как обратиться к text, совершив событие над path
> (например наведение курсора)

Присвойте `id` тексту, который будет размещен в определенном path и допишите правила CSS, которые будут изменять цвет и размер текста при наведении на path:

```
 path:hover {
                        transition: .3s ease;
                        fill:#325288;
                    } 
                    path:hover ~ #t9 {
                       fill:white;
                       font-size:36px;                     
                    }
```

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1565.61 896.1">
            <defs>
                <style>
                    .cls-1,.cls-2 {
                        fill:#b9b9b9;
                    }
                    .cls-1,.cls-2,
                    .cls-3,.cls-4,
                    .cls-5 {
                        stroke:#fff;
                        stroke-width:1.5px;
                    }
                    .cls-1,.cls-3 {
                        stroke-miterlimit:10;
                    }
                    .cls-3,.cls-4 {
                        fill:#cecece;
                    }
                    .cls-5{
                        fill:#fc9272;
                    }
                    path {
                        content: 'blabla';
                        color: red;
                        font-size:20px;
                    }
                    path:hover {
                        transition: .3s ease;
                        fill:#325288;
                    } 
                    path:hover ~ #t9 {
                       fill:white;
                       font-size:36px;                     
                    }
                </style>
            </defs>
            <title>Blank map of Kazakhstan</title>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M69.2,425.5" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-2" d="M241.8,518.1c-.1.1-.3.1-.4.2-.3.1-.5.1-.8.2A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,241.8,518.1Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M241.8,518.1c-.1.1-.3.1-.4.2-.3.1-.5.1-.8.2A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,241.8,518.1Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-3" d="M1195.9,323c-.5,1.7-1.3,1.6-3.9,4.9-2.4,3-2.7,4.4-4.8,5.4a11.24,11.24,0,0,1-2.7.8c-4.3,1.3-6.9,2.1-8.5,4.3a8,8,0,0,0-1.3,4.2c0,1.8.8,2.3,1.2,4.8a10.73,10.73,0,0,1,0,4c-.5,2.4-1.8,2.9-1.9,5.1a8.6,8.6,0,0,0,.5,2.6c1.8,6.9,1.9,7.3,2.5,7.8,1.4,1.2,2.3.3,4.8,1.9a6.65,6.65,0,0,1,2.7,2.8c.3.8.3,1.3-.1,4.5-.5,4.4-.6,5.2-1.3,6a5.58,5.58,0,0,1-2.9,1.6c-4.4,1.8-8.4,6.7-7.5,9.3.6,1.7,2.8,1.2,5.1,4a15.29,15.29,0,0,1,2,4.2c1.6,4.4,2.4,6.7,2.3,8.9a16.83,16.83,0,0,1-3.1,9.2c-1.6,2.7-2.2,4.2-3.8,4.7-2.3.8-3.7-1-6.3,0a8.89,8.89,0,0,0-3.3,2.6c-1.1,1.2-2,2.3-2.1,3.8-.2,2.3,1.8,4.2,2.8,5.2a8.17,8.17,0,0,0,4.5,2.4,6.62,6.62,0,0,0,3.5-.5c.2,1,.5,2,.7,3.1a3.49,3.49,0,0,0-3.8.5,3.26,3.26,0,0,0-.7,3.3c.7,2.4,3.7,3.4,4.2,3.5,2,.6,2.8,0,4.7.9.5.3,2.2,1.1,2.1,2.1s-1.8,1.3-3.8,2.6-2.9,3-4,4.9a21.24,21.24,0,0,0-2.6,8.9c-.6,5.9-1.3,12.6-1.9,20.2a5.5,5.5,0,0,0-3.8,2.1,7.79,7.79,0,0,0-.9,4.5c0,1.7.3,2.1-.1,3-.6,1.4-1.7,1.4-2,2.5-.2.7.1,1.4,2.4,4.6,2.6,3.7,3,4.1,3.7,4.5a9.16,9.16,0,0,0,3.9,1.3,4.42,4.42,0,0,0,2.6,0c1.9-1,.8-5,2.4-5.7.5-.2.8.1,3.4,1a39.72,39.72,0,0,0,4,1.2,18.59,18.59,0,0,0,2.8.5c0,.7-.1,1.4-.1,2,.3.6.6,1.3.9,1.9,0,8.9-.1,17.7-.1,26.6-.6.2-1.6.6-2.7,1a43,43,0,0,0-4.3,1.5,11.25,11.25,0,0,0-3.6,2.6H1167c-.5-.4-1.1-.8-1.6-1.2a25.93,25.93,0,0,1-8.9-.9,22.72,22.72,0,0,1-5.7-2.3c-1.6-1-2.3-1.9-4-2.5a12.21,12.21,0,0,0-4-.4c-3.4.1-5.6-1.2-8.6-2.2-7-2.6-14.5-2.6-16.8-2.6-3.9,0-9.2,0-13.7,2.3-.6.3-1.8,1-3.8,2-3.5,1.8-4.5,1.9-6.6,3.1-3.5,1.9-4.8,3.2-9.2,5.9-4,2.5-3.9,2-6,3.4-3.7,2.5-7,6.7-13.5,15-1.5,1.9-2.7,3.5-4.8,5.9-1.5,1.8-2.8,3.2-3.7,4.3h-15c-.7-.4-1.3-.8-1.9-1.1q-86.4-1.35-172.7-2.6H827c-.4-.4-.9-.8-1.3-1.2H793.6v.3a2.18,2.18,0,0,1-.5-.8c-.3-.6-.3-1.1-.2-3.7.1-2.9.1-3.7-.4-4.4a3.05,3.05,0,0,0-2-1.3c-13.5-.1-26.9-.1-40.4-.1l-15-2.1c-1.1-1.9-2.2-2.5-3-2.6s-1.1.1-1.8-.2c-1.2-.5-1.1-1.6-2.3-2.8s-1.4-.5-3.2-1.9c0,0-.5-.4-2.8-2.8a3.2,3.2,0,0,1-1.9-.7,3.51,3.51,0,0,1-1.2-2.1c-.3-1-1.6-4.7-4.1-5.6a7.54,7.54,0,0,0-2.1-.2c-2.1-.1-3.8,0-4.9,0-6.5-3.9-12.9-7.9-19.4-11.8-3.8-1.4-7.6-2.8-11.5-4.2a26.58,26.58,0,0,0-5.7-3.2,27.83,27.83,0,0,0-4.4-1.4c-3.7-1-4-.4-6.2-1.2a39.43,39.43,0,0,1-4.4-2.5,27.43,27.43,0,0,0-3.2-1.8c-2.1-.8-2.6-.4-4.1-1.2s-1.1-1.3-2.7-2.1c-1.3-.8-1.8-.5-2.8-1.2s-1-1.2-1.9-2.5a9.23,9.23,0,0,0-4.4-3.5c-1.3-.4-2.3-.2-4.1.1-2.3.4-2.8,1-5.7,1.5a20.15,20.15,0,0,1-3,.2c-1.1,0-1.7,0-1.8-.3-.2-.6,2-1.5,4.1-3.9a12.21,12.21,0,0,0,1.2-1.5h.1c3.2-2.9,6.3-5.8,9.5-8.7a7.5,7.5,0,0,0,1.9-.9c2.1-1.3,3-2.8,4.2-4.1,1.7-1.8,3.2-2.3,5.3-3.3,6.9-3.5,16-10.9,18.9-13.2a168.25,168.25,0,0,0,12.5-11.6,2.7,2.7,0,0,0,1.1-1.1,2.52,2.52,0,0,0,.3-1.9c-.4-1-1.7-.6-2.7-1.9-.6-.7-.3-1-1-2.1a10.82,10.82,0,0,0-1.7-1.9c-1-1.3-.2-2.1-1-3.9-.6-1.4-1-1.1-1.8-2.6-.9-1.8-.3-2.3-1.1-3.6a1.38,1.38,0,0,0-.3-.4l1.2-.9c.8-.7,1.5-1.2,3.2-2.7.6-.5,1.5-1.3,2.7-2.3,1.9-1.7,2.2-2.1,2.4-2.6a5.34,5.34,0,0,0,.2-3c-.4-2.4-1.8-3.3-1.3-4.3.2-.4.6-.6,2-1.1,2.6-.8,4.7-1.2,6.5-1.6,2.3-.6,3.5-.8,3.7-1.4.4-1-1.2-1.9-3-5.5-1.4-2.8-1.2-3.6-1-4.1.4-.7,1.2-.9,2-1.2a9.33,9.33,0,0,1,3.3-.3c3,.1,3.6.4,4.1-.1s.2-1.4.2-3.5a57.13,57.13,0,0,1,1.1-7.6c.4-2.3.5-2.6.8-2.8,1.2-.9,3.1.3,7.2,1.7,3.7,1.2,3.3.6,8.1,2,2.6.8,3.7,1.3,7.8,2.5,2.8.8,4.4,1.2,6.2.6a21.78,21.78,0,0,0,2.8-1.3,19,19,0,0,0,3.4-1.8,14.93,14.93,0,0,0,4.1-5.3c1-2,.7-2.1,1.3-2.7,1.1-1,2.1-.4,7.6-.3a2.88,2.88,0,0,1,1.9.5c.9.8.5,2,.9,2.2,1.3.5,8.3-10.8,9.1-13a2,2,0,0,1,1-1.2,2.17,2.17,0,0,1,1-.2c.8.1,2.5-.1,6.3-.7a19.32,19.32,0,0,1,2.8-12.7,19.64,19.64,0,0,1,7.4-6.5,30.33,30.33,0,0,1,4.2-1.6c1.2-2.1,7.8-14.1,13.9-21.9,2.3-2.9,3.5-4.4,5.3-5.8,3.6-2.8,6-2.9,7.1-5.5s-.7-4.3.5-6,3.5-.7,7.6-1.8,8.5-4,9.7-7.9a4.74,4.74,0,0,0,0-3.9,3.68,3.68,0,0,0-1.9-1.6,6.13,6.13,0,0,1,3.8-.5,8.72,8.72,0,0,0,3.1.5c1.7-.2,2.4-1.1,3.8-1.9s3.1-1,6.6-1.4c4.4-.5,6.7-.8,7.8.5.4.4.4.8.7,2.8.9,5.8,1.1,5.6,1.2,7.8.1,3.1.1,4.7-.9,5.9-1.5,1.8-3.8,1.2-4.2,2.6s1.3,3.4,3.1,4c.8.3.9,0,3.5,0a17.42,17.42,0,0,1,3.8.2c1.7.6,1.6,1.8,3.3,3.1a8.16,8.16,0,0,0,6.6,1.2c1.6-.5,2.6-1.6,4.5-3.5,2-2.1,2.3-3.2,3.5-3.3s1.5.9,3.5,1.9a11.66,11.66,0,0,0,5.9.9,14.9,14.9,0,0,0,5.4-1.4c1.9-.8,1.8-1.1,3.1-1.4s2.2-.2,5.4.2c2.2.3,4,.6,4.9.7.2,4.5.5,9.1.7,13.7a5.07,5.07,0,0,0,2.6.7,6.37,6.37,0,0,0,4.7-1.9c1.4-1.4.9-2.6,2.4-3.5.9-.6,1.1-.2,2.6-.7a12.22,12.22,0,0,0,4.9-3.4c1.5-1.6,1.3-1.8,2.3-2.5,1.2-.8,1.7-.4,4.1-1.3s2.9-1.7,3.1-2a3.56,3.56,0,0,0,.3-1.9c0-2.6-.8-3.5-1.1-6.3-.2-1.6-.3-2.5.3-3.4a4.49,4.49,0,0,1,3-1.9,16.7,16.7,0,0,1,3.1-.2,12.72,12.72,0,0,0,3.1-.4c1.4-.7.8-2.3,2.1-4.5.4-.6,1.8-3,4.2-3.6,1.2-.3,2.2-.1,3.6-1a3.07,3.07,0,0,0,1.3-1.2,5.06,5.06,0,0,0,.8-1.9c.5-2.4,3.7-5.4,6.7-5.6a14.84,14.84,0,0,1,2.5.5c3.8,1.1,4.1,2.2,6.4,2.4,1.6.1,2.5-.4,3.2.3a2.45,2.45,0,0,1,.5,2.3c-.1.3-.2.7-2.1,2.4-1.1,1-1.3,1.2-1.4,1.6-.1.7.6,1,1.1,2.1a6.34,6.34,0,0,1,.2,3.8,7.73,7.73,0,0,1-1.4,3.2c-.7,1-1.4,1.4-1.2,1.6s1.6-.2,2.7-.5c2.4-.8,2.4-1.1,3.6-1.4a7.21,7.21,0,0,1,5,.2c1.4.6,1.3,1.3,2.9,1.9a3.52,3.52,0,0,0,3.2.1,2.7,2.7,0,0,0,1.2-1.8c.2-1.4-1.1-1.9-.9-3,.1-.5.9-1.1,2.6-2.3s2-1.3,2.4-1.3c.9,0,1,.8,2.2,1.2a3.7,3.7,0,0,0,3.5-.3,2.9,2.9,0,0,0,1.4-2.6c-.3-1.4-2.2-1.4-2.3-2.6,0-.6.6-1.3,1.9-2.7a13.61,13.61,0,0,1,1.8-1.8c2.2-1.5,4.2.1,5.5-1.2,1-1,0-2,1.2-4.1a5.55,5.55,0,0,1,3.5-2.8,6.15,6.15,0,0,1,2.3.1,28.29,28.29,0,0,0,5.9-.1c2.5-.3,5-.7,5.7-2.3a15.11,15.11,0,0,0,.6-3.5,4.64,4.64,0,0,1,.3-1.7c.5-.6,1.3-.8,3.3-1,3.5-.3,3.6-.2,4.3-.5s.8-.7,2.7-2.8c2.3-2.5,3.2-2.9,3.2-4.1a2.26,2.26,0,0,0-1.2-2.1c-.6-.3-1.3-.1-2.6.2a6.35,6.35,0,0,0-2.1.9,6,6,0,0,0-1.1,1c-.5.5-.5.7-.7.8-.6.3-1.6-.3-2.2-1-.8-1-.4-1.7-1.1-3.2-.6-1.3-1-1.1-2.1-2.7-.3-.4-2-3-1.2-3.9.4-.4,1.3-.3,1.7-.2,1.4.3,1.5,1.2,2.8,1.7a5.15,5.15,0,0,0,3.1,0,7.1,7.1,0,0,0,2.5-1.6c1.9-1.6,6,0,8.6,1.3-.1.1-.2.1-.2.2-.2,1,3.6,3,7.8,4.3,4.4,1.4,5.7.8,6.7,2.2,1.2,1.7.6,4.4-.1,7.9-.5,2.2-1,3.4-.5,5.3a19.85,19.85,0,0,1,.9,2.6,6.48,6.48,0,0,1-.6,4c-.9,1.6-1.8,1.2-3.1,2.8s-1.4,3.7-1.5,5.5c-.1,2-.2,3.3.7,4.2.7.7,1.7.9,3.7,1.2s3.3.6,4.7,0,1.1-1.1,2.4-1.8c1.9-1,3.9-.6,6.3-.2,2.9.5,2.8,1.1,4.8,1.2,1.7,0,2.4-.4,3.9,0,.4.1,2.3.7,2.6,1.9a1.8,1.8,0,0,1-.3,1.2c-.5,1.1-1.2,1.2-1.7,2a3.57,3.57,0,0,0,.2,3.6,2.78,2.78,0,0,0,1.6,1.3,4.4,4.4,0,0,0,2.7-.2c2.8-.7,2.8-1.3,3.6-1.1,1.5.3,1.4,2,3.6,3.2,1.2.6,1.3.2,2.4.7,1.4.8,1.4,1.8,3.6,5.7,1.2,2.1,1.9,3.1,1.9,3.2.8,1,1.4,1.7,1.3,2.6a2.59,2.59,0,0,1-.7,1.5c-.8.9-1.6.7-3.5,1.5a16.88,16.88,0,0,0-3.3,1.9,8.58,8.58,0,0,0-1.9,1.6,4.91,4.91,0,0,0-.6,3.1c.3,1.1.9,1.2,1.1,2.4s-.4,1.4-.1,1.9c.5,1,3.4,1.1,5.2-.2,1.5-1.1.8-2.2,2.2-3.6,1.2-1.2,1.8-.5,5.7-2.2,2.2-1,3.3-1.5,3.8-2.4a2.66,2.66,0,0,1,1.2-1.2,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,1.2-.1,85.21,85.21,0,0,0,12.6.2c1-.1,1.5-.1,2.2-.2a17.26,17.26,0,0,0,6.1-2.5,18.65,18.65,0,0,1,2.8-1.6,6.28,6.28,0,0,1,2.5-.6,4.14,4.14,0,0,1,2.5,1.1c1.3,1,1,1.9,2.2,2.6.2.1,1.3.8,2.1.4s.5-1.3,1.2-2.4a8.22,8.22,0,0,1,2.3-1.8,16.59,16.59,0,0,1,3.8-1.8,5.88,5.88,0,0,1,3.4-.3c1.2.3,1.2.9,2.8,1.7,1,.4,2.4,1.1,3.3.5.7-.5.7-1.6.7-2.4a19.07,19.07,0,0,0-.5-2.6,8.92,8.92,0,0,1,0-3.3,24.9,24.9,0,0,1,1.1-2.6c.6-1.8.2-2.2.7-3.9a15.28,15.28,0,0,1,2-3.6c1.3-2,1.9-2.9,2.6-3.4,1.8-1.2,4.1-.8,5.8-.5a12.23,12.23,0,0,1,6.8,3.8c1,1.2.9,1.7,1.9,2.2,1.8,1.1,3-.2,5.5.4,1.2.3,2.8,1.5,6,4a12.92,12.92,0,0,1,2.2,1.9c2.3,2.9,1.9,6.8,1.9,7.1-.1,1.3-.3,2.4-.3,2.4-.3,1.8-.6,2.4-.3,3.1a2.61,2.61,0,0,0,1.6,1.1,6.15,6.15,0,0,0,1.1.3C1196.3,321.3,1196.2,322.1,1195.9,323Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <text x="170" y="335" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">1</text>
            <text x="230" y="455" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">2</text>
            <text x="260" y="675" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">3</text>
            <text x="430" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">4</text>
            <text x="620" y="595" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">5</text>
            <text x="670" y="205" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">6</text>
            <text x="830" y="75" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">7</text>
            <text x="900" y="235" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">8</text>
            <text id="t9" x="900" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">9</text>
            <text x="860" y="700" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">10</text>
            <text x="990" y="670" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">11</text>
            <text x="1200" y="670" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">12</text>
            <text x="1350" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">13</text>
            <text x="1130" y="185" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">14</text>
        </svg>
```

> как можно прикрепить text к path, или как обращаться к text, если
> буду устанавливать координаты так?

Чтобы найти координаты расположения текста по центру path, используйте метод JS `getBBox()`

```
let bb = t9.getBBox(); 
        console.log(bb.x + bb.width / 2 ); 
        console.log(bb.y + bb.height / 2 );
```

где `id="t9"` идентификатор текста, полученные координаты в консоли подставьте в координаты текста

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1565.61 896.1">
            <defs>
                <style>
                    .cls-1,.cls-2 {
                        fill:#b9b9b9;
                    }
                    .cls-1,.cls-2,
                    .cls-3,.cls-4,
                    .cls-5 {
                        stroke:#fff;
                        stroke-width:1.5px;
                    }
                    .cls-1,.cls-3 {
                        stroke-miterlimit:10;
                    }
                    .cls-3,.cls-4 {
                        fill:#cecece;
                    }
                    .cls-5{
                        fill:#fc9272;
                    }
                    path {
                        content: 'blabla';
                        color: red;
                        font-size:20px;
                    }
                    path:hover {
                        transition: .3s ease;
                        fill:#325288;
                    } 
                    path:hover ~ #t9 {
                       fill:white;
                       font-size:36px;                     
                    }
                </style>
            </defs>
            <title>Blank map of Kazakhstan</title>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M69.2,425.5" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-2" d="M241.8,518.1c-.1.1-.3.1-.4.2-.3.1-.5.1-.8.2A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,241.8,518.1Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-1" d="M241.8,518.1c-.1.1-.3.1-.4.2-.3.1-.5.1-.8.2A8.4,8.4,0,0,1,241.8,518.1Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <path class="cls-3" d="M1195.9,323c-.5,1.7-1.3,1.6-3.9,4.9-2.4,3-2.7,4.4-4.8,5.4a11.24,11.24,0,0,1-2.7.8c-4.3,1.3-6.9,2.1-8.5,4.3a8,8,0,0,0-1.3,4.2c0,1.8.8,2.3,1.2,4.8a10.73,10.73,0,0,1,0,4c-.5,2.4-1.8,2.9-1.9,5.1a8.6,8.6,0,0,0,.5,2.6c1.8,6.9,1.9,7.3,2.5,7.8,1.4,1.2,2.3.3,4.8,1.9a6.65,6.65,0,0,1,2.7,2.8c.3.8.3,1.3-.1,4.5-.5,4.4-.6,5.2-1.3,6a5.58,5.58,0,0,1-2.9,1.6c-4.4,1.8-8.4,6.7-7.5,9.3.6,1.7,2.8,1.2,5.1,4a15.29,15.29,0,0,1,2,4.2c1.6,4.4,2.4,6.7,2.3,8.9a16.83,16.83,0,0,1-3.1,9.2c-1.6,2.7-2.2,4.2-3.8,4.7-2.3.8-3.7-1-6.3,0a8.89,8.89,0,0,0-3.3,2.6c-1.1,1.2-2,2.3-2.1,3.8-.2,2.3,1.8,4.2,2.8,5.2a8.17,8.17,0,0,0,4.5,2.4,6.62,6.62,0,0,0,3.5-.5c.2,1,.5,2,.7,3.1a3.49,3.49,0,0,0-3.8.5,3.26,3.26,0,0,0-.7,3.3c.7,2.4,3.7,3.4,4.2,3.5,2,.6,2.8,0,4.7.9.5.3,2.2,1.1,2.1,2.1s-1.8,1.3-3.8,2.6-2.9,3-4,4.9a21.24,21.24,0,0,0-2.6,8.9c-.6,5.9-1.3,12.6-1.9,20.2a5.5,5.5,0,0,0-3.8,2.1,7.79,7.79,0,0,0-.9,4.5c0,1.7.3,2.1-.1,3-.6,1.4-1.7,1.4-2,2.5-.2.7.1,1.4,2.4,4.6,2.6,3.7,3,4.1,3.7,4.5a9.16,9.16,0,0,0,3.9,1.3,4.42,4.42,0,0,0,2.6,0c1.9-1,.8-5,2.4-5.7.5-.2.8.1,3.4,1a39.72,39.72,0,0,0,4,1.2,18.59,18.59,0,0,0,2.8.5c0,.7-.1,1.4-.1,2,.3.6.6,1.3.9,1.9,0,8.9-.1,17.7-.1,26.6-.6.2-1.6.6-2.7,1a43,43,0,0,0-4.3,1.5,11.25,11.25,0,0,0-3.6,2.6H1167c-.5-.4-1.1-.8-1.6-1.2a25.93,25.93,0,0,1-8.9-.9,22.72,22.72,0,0,1-5.7-2.3c-1.6-1-2.3-1.9-4-2.5a12.21,12.21,0,0,0-4-.4c-3.4.1-5.6-1.2-8.6-2.2-7-2.6-14.5-2.6-16.8-2.6-3.9,0-9.2,0-13.7,2.3-.6.3-1.8,1-3.8,2-3.5,1.8-4.5,1.9-6.6,3.1-3.5,1.9-4.8,3.2-9.2,5.9-4,2.5-3.9,2-6,3.4-3.7,2.5-7,6.7-13.5,15-1.5,1.9-2.7,3.5-4.8,5.9-1.5,1.8-2.8,3.2-3.7,4.3h-15c-.7-.4-1.3-.8-1.9-1.1q-86.4-1.35-172.7-2.6H827c-.4-.4-.9-.8-1.3-1.2H793.6v.3a2.18,2.18,0,0,1-.5-.8c-.3-.6-.3-1.1-.2-3.7.1-2.9.1-3.7-.4-4.4a3.05,3.05,0,0,0-2-1.3c-13.5-.1-26.9-.1-40.4-.1l-15-2.1c-1.1-1.9-2.2-2.5-3-2.6s-1.1.1-1.8-.2c-1.2-.5-1.1-1.6-2.3-2.8s-1.4-.5-3.2-1.9c0,0-.5-.4-2.8-2.8a3.2,3.2,0,0,1-1.9-.7,3.51,3.51,0,0,1-1.2-2.1c-.3-1-1.6-4.7-4.1-5.6a7.54,7.54,0,0,0-2.1-.2c-2.1-.1-3.8,0-4.9,0-6.5-3.9-12.9-7.9-19.4-11.8-3.8-1.4-7.6-2.8-11.5-4.2a26.58,26.58,0,0,0-5.7-3.2,27.83,27.83,0,0,0-4.4-1.4c-3.7-1-4-.4-6.2-1.2a39.43,39.43,0,0,1-4.4-2.5,27.43,27.43,0,0,0-3.2-1.8c-2.1-.8-2.6-.4-4.1-1.2s-1.1-1.3-2.7-2.1c-1.3-.8-1.8-.5-2.8-1.2s-1-1.2-1.9-2.5a9.23,9.23,0,0,0-4.4-3.5c-1.3-.4-2.3-.2-4.1.1-2.3.4-2.8,1-5.7,1.5a20.15,20.15,0,0,1-3,.2c-1.1,0-1.7,0-1.8-.3-.2-.6,2-1.5,4.1-3.9a12.21,12.21,0,0,0,1.2-1.5h.1c3.2-2.9,6.3-5.8,9.5-8.7a7.5,7.5,0,0,0,1.9-.9c2.1-1.3,3-2.8,4.2-4.1,1.7-1.8,3.2-2.3,5.3-3.3,6.9-3.5,16-10.9,18.9-13.2a168.25,168.25,0,0,0,12.5-11.6,2.7,2.7,0,0,0,1.1-1.1,2.52,2.52,0,0,0,.3-1.9c-.4-1-1.7-.6-2.7-1.9-.6-.7-.3-1-1-2.1a10.82,10.82,0,0,0-1.7-1.9c-1-1.3-.2-2.1-1-3.9-.6-1.4-1-1.1-1.8-2.6-.9-1.8-.3-2.3-1.1-3.6a1.38,1.38,0,0,0-.3-.4l1.2-.9c.8-.7,1.5-1.2,3.2-2.7.6-.5,1.5-1.3,2.7-2.3,1.9-1.7,2.2-2.1,2.4-2.6a5.34,5.34,0,0,0,.2-3c-.4-2.4-1.8-3.3-1.3-4.3.2-.4.6-.6,2-1.1,2.6-.8,4.7-1.2,6.5-1.6,2.3-.6,3.5-.8,3.7-1.4.4-1-1.2-1.9-3-5.5-1.4-2.8-1.2-3.6-1-4.1.4-.7,1.2-.9,2-1.2a9.33,9.33,0,0,1,3.3-.3c3,.1,3.6.4,4.1-.1s.2-1.4.2-3.5a57.13,57.13,0,0,1,1.1-7.6c.4-2.3.5-2.6.8-2.8,1.2-.9,3.1.3,7.2,1.7,3.7,1.2,3.3.6,8.1,2,2.6.8,3.7,1.3,7.8,2.5,2.8.8,4.4,1.2,6.2.6a21.78,21.78,0,0,0,2.8-1.3,19,19,0,0,0,3.4-1.8,14.93,14.93,0,0,0,4.1-5.3c1-2,.7-2.1,1.3-2.7,1.1-1,2.1-.4,7.6-.3a2.88,2.88,0,0,1,1.9.5c.9.8.5,2,.9,2.2,1.3.5,8.3-10.8,9.1-13a2,2,0,0,1,1-1.2,2.17,2.17,0,0,1,1-.2c.8.1,2.5-.1,6.3-.7a19.32,19.32,0,0,1,2.8-12.7,19.64,19.64,0,0,1,7.4-6.5,30.33,30.33,0,0,1,4.2-1.6c1.2-2.1,7.8-14.1,13.9-21.9,2.3-2.9,3.5-4.4,5.3-5.8,3.6-2.8,6-2.9,7.1-5.5s-.7-4.3.5-6,3.5-.7,7.6-1.8,8.5-4,9.7-7.9a4.74,4.74,0,0,0,0-3.9,3.68,3.68,0,0,0-1.9-1.6,6.13,6.13,0,0,1,3.8-.5,8.72,8.72,0,0,0,3.1.5c1.7-.2,2.4-1.1,3.8-1.9s3.1-1,6.6-1.4c4.4-.5,6.7-.8,7.8.5.4.4.4.8.7,2.8.9,5.8,1.1,5.6,1.2,7.8.1,3.1.1,4.7-.9,5.9-1.5,1.8-3.8,1.2-4.2,2.6s1.3,3.4,3.1,4c.8.3.9,0,3.5,0a17.42,17.42,0,0,1,3.8.2c1.7.6,1.6,1.8,3.3,3.1a8.16,8.16,0,0,0,6.6,1.2c1.6-.5,2.6-1.6,4.5-3.5,2-2.1,2.3-3.2,3.5-3.3s1.5.9,3.5,1.9a11.66,11.66,0,0,0,5.9.9,14.9,14.9,0,0,0,5.4-1.4c1.9-.8,1.8-1.1,3.1-1.4s2.2-.2,5.4.2c2.2.3,4,.6,4.9.7.2,4.5.5,9.1.7,13.7a5.07,5.07,0,0,0,2.6.7,6.37,6.37,0,0,0,4.7-1.9c1.4-1.4.9-2.6,2.4-3.5.9-.6,1.1-.2,2.6-.7a12.22,12.22,0,0,0,4.9-3.4c1.5-1.6,1.3-1.8,2.3-2.5,1.2-.8,1.7-.4,4.1-1.3s2.9-1.7,3.1-2a3.56,3.56,0,0,0,.3-1.9c0-2.6-.8-3.5-1.1-6.3-.2-1.6-.3-2.5.3-3.4a4.49,4.49,0,0,1,3-1.9,16.7,16.7,0,0,1,3.1-.2,12.72,12.72,0,0,0,3.1-.4c1.4-.7.8-2.3,2.1-4.5.4-.6,1.8-3,4.2-3.6,1.2-.3,2.2-.1,3.6-1a3.07,3.07,0,0,0,1.3-1.2,5.06,5.06,0,0,0,.8-1.9c.5-2.4,3.7-5.4,6.7-5.6a14.84,14.84,0,0,1,2.5.5c3.8,1.1,4.1,2.2,6.4,2.4,1.6.1,2.5-.4,3.2.3a2.45,2.45,0,0,1,.5,2.3c-.1.3-.2.7-2.1,2.4-1.1,1-1.3,1.2-1.4,1.6-.1.7.6,1,1.1,2.1a6.34,6.34,0,0,1,.2,3.8,7.73,7.73,0,0,1-1.4,3.2c-.7,1-1.4,1.4-1.2,1.6s1.6-.2,2.7-.5c2.4-.8,2.4-1.1,3.6-1.4a7.21,7.21,0,0,1,5,.2c1.4.6,1.3,1.3,2.9,1.9a3.52,3.52,0,0,0,3.2.1,2.7,2.7,0,0,0,1.2-1.8c.2-1.4-1.1-1.9-.9-3,.1-.5.9-1.1,2.6-2.3s2-1.3,2.4-1.3c.9,0,1,.8,2.2,1.2a3.7,3.7,0,0,0,3.5-.3,2.9,2.9,0,0,0,1.4-2.6c-.3-1.4-2.2-1.4-2.3-2.6,0-.6.6-1.3,1.9-2.7a13.61,13.61,0,0,1,1.8-1.8c2.2-1.5,4.2.1,5.5-1.2,1-1,0-2,1.2-4.1a5.55,5.55,0,0,1,3.5-2.8,6.15,6.15,0,0,1,2.3.1,28.29,28.29,0,0,0,5.9-.1c2.5-.3,5-.7,5.7-2.3a15.11,15.11,0,0,0,.6-3.5,4.64,4.64,0,0,1,.3-1.7c.5-.6,1.3-.8,3.3-1,3.5-.3,3.6-.2,4.3-.5s.8-.7,2.7-2.8c2.3-2.5,3.2-2.9,3.2-4.1a2.26,2.26,0,0,0-1.2-2.1c-.6-.3-1.3-.1-2.6.2a6.35,6.35,0,0,0-2.1.9,6,6,0,0,0-1.1,1c-.5.5-.5.7-.7.8-.6.3-1.6-.3-2.2-1-.8-1-.4-1.7-1.1-3.2-.6-1.3-1-1.1-2.1-2.7-.3-.4-2-3-1.2-3.9.4-.4,1.3-.3,1.7-.2,1.4.3,1.5,1.2,2.8,1.7a5.15,5.15,0,0,0,3.1,0,7.1,7.1,0,0,0,2.5-1.6c1.9-1.6,6,0,8.6,1.3-.1.1-.2.1-.2.2-.2,1,3.6,3,7.8,4.3,4.4,1.4,5.7.8,6.7,2.2,1.2,1.7.6,4.4-.1,7.9-.5,2.2-1,3.4-.5,5.3a19.85,19.85,0,0,1,.9,2.6,6.48,6.48,0,0,1-.6,4c-.9,1.6-1.8,1.2-3.1,2.8s-1.4,3.7-1.5,5.5c-.1,2-.2,3.3.7,4.2.7.7,1.7.9,3.7,1.2s3.3.6,4.7,0,1.1-1.1,2.4-1.8c1.9-1,3.9-.6,6.3-.2,2.9.5,2.8,1.1,4.8,1.2,1.7,0,2.4-.4,3.9,0,.4.1,2.3.7,2.6,1.9a1.8,1.8,0,0,1-.3,1.2c-.5,1.1-1.2,1.2-1.7,2a3.57,3.57,0,0,0,.2,3.6,2.78,2.78,0,0,0,1.6,1.3,4.4,4.4,0,0,0,2.7-.2c2.8-.7,2.8-1.3,3.6-1.1,1.5.3,1.4,2,3.6,3.2,1.2.6,1.3.2,2.4.7,1.4.8,1.4,1.8,3.6,5.7,1.2,2.1,1.9,3.1,1.9,3.2.8,1,1.4,1.7,1.3,2.6a2.59,2.59,0,0,1-.7,1.5c-.8.9-1.6.7-3.5,1.5a16.88,16.88,0,0,0-3.3,1.9,8.58,8.58,0,0,0-1.9,1.6,4.91,4.91,0,0,0-.6,3.1c.3,1.1.9,1.2,1.1,2.4s-.4,1.4-.1,1.9c.5,1,3.4,1.1,5.2-.2,1.5-1.1.8-2.2,2.2-3.6,1.2-1.2,1.8-.5,5.7-2.2,2.2-1,3.3-1.5,3.8-2.4a2.66,2.66,0,0,1,1.2-1.2,2.7,2.7,0,0,1,1.2-.1,85.21,85.21,0,0,0,12.6.2c1-.1,1.5-.1,2.2-.2a17.26,17.26,0,0,0,6.1-2.5,18.65,18.65,0,0,1,2.8-1.6,6.28,6.28,0,0,1,2.5-.6,4.14,4.14,0,0,1,2.5,1.1c1.3,1,1,1.9,2.2,2.6.2.1,1.3.8,2.1.4s.5-1.3,1.2-2.4a8.22,8.22,0,0,1,2.3-1.8,16.59,16.59,0,0,1,3.8-1.8,5.88,5.88,0,0,1,3.4-.3c1.2.3,1.2.9,2.8,1.7,1,.4,2.4,1.1,3.3.5.7-.5.7-1.6.7-2.4a19.07,19.07,0,0,0-.5-2.6,8.92,8.92,0,0,1,0-3.3,24.9,24.9,0,0,1,1.1-2.6c.6-1.8.2-2.2.7-3.9a15.28,15.28,0,0,1,2-3.6c1.3-2,1.9-2.9,2.6-3.4,1.8-1.2,4.1-.8,5.8-.5a12.23,12.23,0,0,1,6.8,3.8c1,1.2.9,1.7,1.9,2.2,1.8,1.1,3-.2,5.5.4,1.2.3,2.8,1.5,6,4a12.92,12.92,0,0,1,2.2,1.9c2.3,2.9,1.9,6.8,1.9,7.1-.1,1.3-.3,2.4-.3,2.4-.3,1.8-.6,2.4-.3,3.1a2.61,2.61,0,0,0,1.6,1.1,6.15,6.15,0,0,0,1.1.3C1196.3,321.3,1196.2,322.1,1195.9,323Z" transform="translate(-0.64 -0.37)"/>
            <text x="170" y="335" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">1</text>
            <text x="230" y="455" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">2</text>
            <text x="260" y="675" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">3</text>
            <text x="430" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">4</text>
            <text x="620" y="595" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">5</text>
            <text x="670" y="205" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">6</text>
            <text x="830" y="75" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">7</text>
            <text x="900" y="235" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">8</text>
            <text id="t9" x="954.3" y="429.9" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle"   font-size="26" fill="black">Казахстан</text>
            <text x="860" y="700" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">10</text>
            <text x="990" y="670" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">11</text>
            <text x="1200" y="670" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">12</text>
            <text x="1350" y="435" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">13</text>
            <text x="1130" y="185" dominant-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" font-size="26" fill="black">14</text>
        </svg>  
        
        <script>
        let bb = t9.getBBox(); 
        console.log(bb.x + bb.width / 2 ); 
        console.log(bb.y + bb.height / 2 );
        
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

[BONUS]

### Карта Казахстана

Анимация прорисовки границ, с последующим заполнением цветом, анимация появления столицы Казахстана

- По окончании анимации прорисовки контуров карты и заполнения её
  цветом начинается анимация текста - названия государства.

```
    <text x="40" y="50"  font-size="12"  fill="none" stroke="none" >Казахстан 
         <animate id="fillKaz" dur="1.5s" begin="fillPath.end"  repeatCount="1"
            attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
     </text>
```

- Затем начинается цепочка последовательных анимаций:   прорисовки
  знака столицы

```
      <g  opacity="0">
        <circle cx="68" cy="35" r="2" fill="#787A78" stroke="none"  />
        <circle cx="68" cy="35" r="0.8" fill="#787A78" stroke="white" stroke-
             width="0.5" />
        <animate id="fillCircle" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" 
             begin="fillKaz.end" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze" />
        </g>
```

- названия столицы государства:

```
    <text x="70" y="32" font-size="5"  fill="none" stroke="none"> Нур-Султан 
      <animate id="fillAstana" dur="1.5s" begin="fillCircle.end"  repeatCount="1"
            attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
     </text>
```

**Ниже полый код анимации:**

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 120 120"  >
<path id="KZ" title="Kazakhstan" class="land" transform="translate(-603 -260)" fill="none" stroke="grey" stroke-width="0.2" stroke-dasharray="395" stroke-dashoffset="395" d="M674.22,333.11L672.61,333.81L668.92,336.42L667.69,339.07L666.64,339.09L665.88,337.34L662.31,337.22L661.74,334.16L660.37,334.13L660.58,330.33L657.23,327.53L652.42,327.83L649.13,328.39L646.45,324.89L644.16,323.41L639.81,320.57L639.29,320.22L632.07,322.57L632.18,336.7L630.74,336.88L628.78,333.95L626.88,332.89L623.7,333.68L622.46,334.93L622.3,334.01L622.99,332.44L622.46,331.12L619.21,329.82L617.94,326.35L616.4,325.37L616.3,324.09L619.03,324.46L619.14,321.58L621.52,320.94L623.97,321.53L624.48,317.62L623.98,315.11L621.17,315.31L618.79,314.31L615.54,316.1L612.93,316.96L611.5,316.3L611.79,314.2L610,311.44L607.92,311.55L605.54,308.72L607.16,305.5L606.34,304.63L608.57,299.86L611.46,302.39L611.81,299.2L617.59,294.35L621.97,294.23L628.16,297.33L631.47,299.12L634.45,297.25L638.89,297.17L642.48,299.46L643.3,298.15L647.23,298.34L647.94,296.23L643.39,293.14L646.08,290.91L645.56,289.66L648.25,288.45L646.23,285.25L647.51,283.63L658,281.97L659.37,280.78L666.39,278.99L668.91,276.95L673.95,278.01L674.83,283.02L677.76,281.86L681.36,283.49L681.13,286.07L683.82,285.8L690.84,281.31L689.82,282.81L693.4,286.47L699.66,298.05L701.16,295.72L705.02,298.28L709.05,297.14L710.59,297.94L711.94,300.49L713.9,301.33L715.1,303.18L718.71,302.6L720.2,305.23L718.06,308.06L715.73,308.46L715.6,312.64L714.04,314.5L708.48,313.15L706.46,320.41L705.02,321.3L699.47,322.88L701.99,329.63L700.07,330.63L700.29,332.79L698.56,332.24L697.16,330.87L693,330.47L688.35,330.37L687.33,330.79L683.33,329.18L681.74,329.98L681.31,332.22L676.69,330.91L674.85,331.45z">
 <animate id="dash" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" dur="4s" fill="freeze" values="395;0"/> 
<animate id="fillPath" attributeName="fill" values="white;#AFCD72" begin="dash.end" dur="1s" fill="freeze" />
</path>  

<text x="40" y="50"  font-size="12"  fill="none" stroke="none" >Казахстан 
     <animate id="fillKaz" dur="1.5s" begin="fillPath.end"  repeatCount="1"
        attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
 </text>

<g  opacity="0">
<circle cx="68" cy="35" r="2" fill="#787A78" stroke="none"  />
<circle cx="68" cy="35" r="0.8" fill="#787A78" stroke="white" stroke-width="0.5" />
<animate id="fillCircle" attributeName="opacity" values="0;1" begin="fillKaz.end" dur="0.8s" fill="freeze" />
</g>
 
 <text x="70" y="32" font-size="5"  fill="none" stroke="none"   >Астана 
  <animate id="fillAstana" dur="1.5s" begin="fillCircle.end"  repeatCount="1"
        attributeName="fill"   values="#AFCD72;#787A78" fill="freeze" />
 </text>

</svg>
```